# Org link search fallback, if no matching headlines?

Tags: org-mode

With the variable `org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline` you can only choose between various search options but I would like to have the following behaviour:

- First try to match against headlines only
- If the above fails fallback to searching the whole buffer

Is there an option for this, or how could I achieve that?

Comment: I think that is the default behaviour, see the [internal links section](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html#Internal-links) in the manual.

Comment: @suvayu If you set the above variable to `t` it will match against the corresponding headline, if you set it to nil it will match other things in the buffer, I want it to match against headlines first and *only* if it fails match against other things. It does not work on my side this way, it will jump to any string matching the link if I set the variable to nil even if there is a matching headline.

Comment: Looks like it's an either or.  The manual seems to suggest otherwise.  I would report this to the Org mailing list.  Either the code should add this feature, or the documentation should be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked around it with the following for now:

```
(setq org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline nil)
```

and replaced links to headlines with `[[*Headline name][Link name]]` and links
to inline text with `[[In line text to search for][Link name]]`.

The first will only match against headlines.